# CSS or jQuery sliding border-bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/axe3J/

I'm trying to make the border-bottom slide and change from blue to red when I hover over 2-5. I have never used jQuery so I'm hoping it's possible with just CSS. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="1.html" class="button" id="current">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="2.html" class="button">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="3.html" class="button">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="4.html" class="button">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="5.html" class="button">5</a></li> 
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
display: inline;
}

.button {
padding: 5px 35px 5px 35px;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
color: #d0332b;
border-bottom: 7px solid #d0332b;
}

#current {
border-bottom: 7px solid #09C;
color: #09C;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS works just fine. So, what do you want us to do?

Comment: I want the border-bottom to slide.

Comment: You want what to slide? There are two border bottoms the one on hover that is red and the currently selected one which is blue, do you want the blue bar to slide when you click on another one?

Comment: Yeah I want the blue bar to slide when I hover over another one (and if possible, change color to red).

Comment: Turns red while sliding or at the end of sliding it turns red?

Comment: Turns red while sliding.

Comment: looking for something like this : http://codepen.io/elneco/pen/kljCK

Comment: Yes, exactly that! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I think that what he was looking for @codeSpy.

Comment: Pure CSS3 goodness, nice @codeSpy

Comment: Alright I have another problem now. This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/p9tBR/

When I'm on page '2' the slider starts from 1 again. I want it to start on the page I am. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css3 transition.
add  a span tag into your a tag.

```
<li><a href="1.html" class="button" id="current">1 <span class="border"></a></span></li>
<li><a href="2.html" class="button">2 <span class="border"></a></span></li>
```

css

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:20px;
}
li span.border{
    height:5px;
    width:150px;
    left:-150px;
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
     -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    bottom:0;
}
li a#current span.border{
    left:0;
    background:red;
}
li:hover span.border{
    left:0;
}
```

I think you got the idea. please change the css for your need. thanks.